# Do Chrome Apps have the same permissions available to them as Extensions?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

This page:https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browsingData

softly suggests no with the wording of things like:
You must declare the "browsingData" permission in the extension manifest to use this API.

presumably there is a difference between the app and extension manifest?

Comment: I rolled back your edit - you should instead add a comment on the answer. Have a loot at the site [tour] for a better explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Here is a [list of permissions an App](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/declare_permissions) can declare and here is a [list of permissions an extension](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/declare_permissions) can declare. There is a lot of overlap but app permissions tend towards self contained functionality while extensions are geared more towards interacting with other tabs and websites you visit.

Comment: thanks very much abraham! does it seem strange that a chrome app would have no way of accessing browsing history while an android app does have a permission for this?

Comment: Not really. They are completely different platforms with different goals.